# Query builder improvement

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this following query builder.
Some of the cases has the same peice of code (those who have parameter).

I know its not good to duplicate code that much if at all.

How would you suggest me to improve this loop?
Thanks !

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
    switch ($conditions[$i]['condition']) {
        case 'version':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`app_version` = :value'.$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'except_version':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`app_version` != :value'.$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'from_credits':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`credits` >= :value'.$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'to_credits':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`credits` <= :value'.$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'no_credits':
            $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`credits` = 0';
            break;
        case 'register_atleast':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= ' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `musers`.`creation_date`) > :value'.$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'talked_atleast':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= " AND `musers`.`total_talktime` >= :value".$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'never_talked':
            $sql .= " AND `musers`.`total_talktime` = 0";
            break;
        case 'purchase_atleast':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= " AND `musers`.`purchase_times` >= :value".$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'never_purchase':
            $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`purchase_times` = 0';
            break;
        case 'from_birthdate':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= " AND (`musers`.`birthdate` = '0000-00-00' OR `musers`.`birthdate` >= :value".$value_counter." )";
            $values[$value_counter] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($conditions[$i]['value']));
            break;
        case 'to_birthdate':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= " AND (`musers`.`birthdate` = '0000-00-00' OR `musers`.`birthdate` <= :value".$value_counter." )";
            $values[$value_counter] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($conditions[$i]['value']));
            break;
        case 'from_creation_date':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= " AND (`musers`.`creation_date` = '0000-00-00' OR `musers`.`creation_date` >= :value".$value_counter." )";
            $values[$value_counter] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($conditions[$i]['value']));
            break;
        case 'to_creation_date':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= " AND (`musers`.`creation_date` = '0000-00-00' OR `musers`.`creation_date` <= :value".$value_counter." )";
            $values[$value_counter] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($conditions[$i]['value']));
            break;
        case 'user_id':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`id` = :value'.$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'visit_app_aleast':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`visit_app_times` >= :value'.$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'visit_app_less':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`visit_app_times` < :value'.$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'total_calls_atleast':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`total_calls` >= :value'.$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'total_calls_less':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`total_calls` < :value'.$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
        case 'hourdiff':
            $value_counter++;
            $sql .= ' AND `hourdiff` = :value'.$value_counter;
            $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: - Posted there, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, if you want to avoid code duplication, you extract the duplicated code in functiond or object methods. Even for 3 lines of code, if it's repeated, it worth creating a function and call it anywhere you need these 3 lines of code.

There's another way, in your particular case : stack the case in your switch structure.

```
switch($conditions[$i]['condition']) {
    case 'version':
    case 'except_version':
    case 'from_credits':
        $value_counter++;
        $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`app_version` = :value'.$value_counter;
        $values[$value_counter] = $conditions[$i]['value'];
        break;
     case 'no_credits':
        $sql .= ' AND `musers`.`credits` = 0';
        break;
     // etc.
}
```

Have a look on the "switch" documentation for more explanations :)

Comment: please notice you used the same sql subquery for different conditions.
it won't solve me the problem this way. thanks for trying thou :)

Comment: Nope you didn't. the code duplication is only the lines with $value_counter++, and $values[$value_counter].
Please notice the $sql.= is changing inside every case!.
your solution doesn't solve the problem and will just cause the problem to act wrong. (wrong queries)